# Cauchy sequence - trick question?

Tags: cauchy-sequences

The question is the following:

Show that if a subsequence $\{x_{n_k} \}$ of a Cauchy sequence $\{ x_n\}$ is convergent, then $\{x_n\}$ is convergent.

I thought that all Cauchy sequences are convergent. At least in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: But the question didn't specify $\mathbb R$.  In $\mathbb Q$, for example, it's easy to find Cauchy sequences which do not converge.

Comment: I am quite certain they meant $\mathbb{R}$. Hmm.. Ok. What would be an example of such a sequence?

Comment: Over $\mathbb Q$, take $\{1,1.4,1.41,1.414,1.4142,\cdots\}$ where $a_n$ is the first $n$ digits in $\sqrt 2$.  Of course that converges in $\mathbb R$, but $\sqrt 2$ is not rational.

Comment: The question does not presume the Cauchy criterion to be known.

Comment: The point here is that if the subsequence converges to $L$ then, since all the elements in the sequence approach each other, then they must approach $L$.

Answer (score 1):

One way of proving that every Cauchy sequence (in $\mathbb R$) converges is to follow these steps:

1) Prove every Cauchy sequence is bounded

2) Use Bolzano-Weierstrass to prove every Cauchy sequence thus has a convergent subsequence

3) Prove that if a Cauchy sequence has at least one convergent subsequence, then the full sequence converges to the same limit.

You're just being asked to prove the last step.